# How to get and set custom 'Web' properties in SharePoint online using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, sub-site

I want to save some `custom properties` to `web` and access these properties for later use. Is it possible using `JavaScript object model`? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read/write to web property bag using JavaScript object model.  Example of reading the custom property:

```
//wait until client object model dependencies are loaded before executing our code
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebProperties, "sp.js");

var webProperties;

function getWebProperties() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    webProperties = clientContext.get_web().get_allProperties();
    clientContext.load(webProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.getWebPropertiesSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function getWebPropertiesSucceeded() {

          //debugger; //use this to force a break here
    //returns an object with all properties.  
          //Use the quick watch to expand this out to see all of them.
    var allProps = webProperties.get_fieldValues();

    var customProp = "";

         //make sure the property is there before using it.
    if(webProperties.get_fieldValues().CustomSite_Version != undefined)
    {
        var customProp = webProperties.get_fieldValues().CustomSite_Version;
    }
    alert(customProp);
}

function onQueryFailed(args, sender)
{
     //handle errors here
}
```

Source: [Accessing the web property bag with JavaScript](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/accessing-the-web-property-bag-with-javascript/)

Example of setting custom property:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {


            var hostweburl = "http://siteURL/";


            var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";


            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
                function () {
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", execOperation);
                }
            );
        });


        function execOperation() {


            AddWebSiteProperties("http://siteURL");

        }
        function AddWebSiteProperties(siteUrl) {

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

            oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
            alert(oWebsite);

            clientContext.load(oWebsite);
            alert("Load");
            var props = oWebsite.get_allProperties();

            props.set_item("Myproperty", "PropertyValue");
            oWebsite.update();
            clientContext.load(oWebsite);

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded2),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed2)
             );
        }






        function onQuerySucceeded2(sender, args) {
            alert("Success");         }

        function onQueryFailed2(sender, args) {
            alert("Failed");
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }

</script>
```

Source: [Add properties to SPWeb property bag using JSOM in SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2013/05/06/how-to-add-properties-to-spweb-property-bag-using-jsom-in-sharepoint-2013/)